# Print custom attribute in view from different controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying print a custom attribute in a `.cshtml` view and I was reading this thread: [asp.net mvc custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403856/asp-net-mvc-custom-attributes)
It's very simple.

**My custom attribute**

```
public class TitleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        protected string description;

        public TitleAttribute(String descritionIn)
        {
            this.description = descritionIn;
        }

        public String Description
        {
            get
            {
                return this.description;
            }
        }
    }
```

But this attribute can be used in different controllers and print this value in a shared layout.

**HomeController**

```
[Title("Start Page")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

**RequestController**

```
[Title("This page is releated with request")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Is possible print the custom attribute value without use `Reflection`?

Comment: [No](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s1zwct(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your point you'll need to modify your attribute to smth like:

```
public class TitleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        protected string description;

        public TitleAttribute(String descritionIn)
        {
            this.description = descritionIn;
        }

        public String Description
        {
            get
            {
                return this.description;
            }
        }

        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Title = description;
        }
    }
```